# Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 (Clang failed with code 1)

Tags: xcode, llvm

I have question regarding xcode project,

I am very new in xcoding .I am trying to import and run this project in my xcode to test how its work https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc, but as soon as i run the project i go the following error

I am using IOS SDK 6.1 and Apple LLVM compiler 4.2.

error

```
ProcessPCH /Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SocketTesterARC-Prefix-eaouggsjdwbakedoogkslkipaiwy/SocketTesterARC-Prefix.pch.pth SocketTesterARC/SocketTesterARC-Prefix.pch normal i386 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/nikunjpatel/Desktop/socket.IO-objc-master
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -mios-simulator-version-min=4.0 -iquote /Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/SocketTesterARC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketTesterARC.build/SocketTesterARC-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/SocketTesterARC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketTesterARC.build/SocketTesterARC-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/SocketTesterARC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketTesterARC.build/SocketTesterARC-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/SocketTesterARC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketTesterARC.build/SocketTesterARC-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/SocketTesterARC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketTesterARC.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/SocketTesterARC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketTesterARC.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SocketTesterARC-Prefix-eaouggsjdwbakedoogkslkipaiwy/SocketTesterARC-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/nikunjpatel/Desktop/socket.IO-objc-master/SocketTesterARC/SocketTesterARC-Prefix.pch -o /Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SocketTesterARC-Prefix-eaouggsjdwbakedoogkslkipaiwy/SocketTesterARC-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/nikunjpatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SocketTesterARC-hbuecoaldjcdawhaiejruwwnvccu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SocketTesterARC-Prefix-eaouggsjdwbakedoogkslkipaiwy/SocketTesterARC-Prefix.pch.d

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nikunjpatel/Desktop/socket.IO-objc-master/SocketTesterARC/SocketTesterARC-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

please help me